# Convert screen command for tmux

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

Is anyone familiar with how to run programs from crontab in tmux instead of a screen session?

For instance what would be the command line equivalent of this:

```
@reboot cd /home/morggin/mcserver && screen -dmS McMyAdmin ./MCMA2_Linux_x86_64
```

Comment: `tmux new -d -s McMyAdmin ./MCMA2_Linux_x86_64`...

Comment: Thank you jasonwryan!! so that would be -d to demonize or start it as a detached session and -s McMyAdmin to name the panel correct?

Comment: No. I have never used screen much.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that from one command as Jason indicated. You can do

```
 tmux new-session -d -s session_name your_command
```

The `-d` detaches the new session from the terminal. It might not needed when not started from a cron job instead from a terminal, but it won't hurt. (`new` is short for `new-session`)

This has one major disadvantage in that it closes that session if`your_command` terminates, and if anything useful is written to the session, that info is lost.
I suggest you use a multi-line script to start these kind of commands and start that from your cron at reboot:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/morggin/mcserver
tmux new-session -d -s McMyAdmin -n McMyAdmin
tmux send-keys "./MCMA2_Linux_x86_64"
```

which starts the program in the bash session tmux creates anyway (there are other ways to prevent program exit to close a window, but from what I recall some involve double `bash` startups). The `-n` names the window within the session, useful in case you decide to add creation of multiple windows in the session.